# Overriding default animation parameters with custom values

Tags: javascript, animation, configuration

Using JavaScript ES5, I would like to know if you could suggest me a more "elegant" and succinct way to overriding defaults variable when User pass custom values.

In the following example, an [animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API) is executed using `_defaultOptions`, a developer can change the default behavior passing only some properties to a function, example:

`animate(dom, {duration: 2000}); // overriding only duration, rest as default`

Notes:

- I need also to support IE 11.
- `optionsArg` is optional, so `animate(dom)` is allowed

```js
var dom = document.getElementById('logo');

var _defaultOptions = {
  duration: 1000,
  delay: 0,
  iterations: 1,
  direction: 'normal',
  fill: 'both'
};

var animate = function(dom, optionsArg) {
  // code to be improved here
  var options = {
    duration: optionsArg && 'duration' in optionsArg ? optionsArg.duration : _defaultOptions.duration,
    delay: optionsArg && 'delay' in optionsArg ? optionsArg.delay : _defaultOptions.delay,
    iterations: optionsArg && 'iterations' in optionsArg ? optionsArg.iterations : _defaultOptions.iterations,
    direction: optionsArg && 'direction' in optionsArg ? optionsArg.direction : _defaultOptions.direction,
    fill: optionsArg && 'fill' in optionsArg ? optionsArg.fill : _defaultOptions.fill,
  };
  dom.animate([{
    opacity: 1
  }, {
    opacity: 0
  }], options);
};

animate(dom, {duration: 2000});
```

```html
<img id="logo" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e5/NASA_logo.svg">
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Object.assign(_defaultOptions, optionsArg )
```

But this will have side effects as it changes `_defaultOptions` object itself.

Comment: Can you clarify it?

Moreover following code will not cause any side effect.
Object.assign( Object.create(_defaultOptions), optionsArg )

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am aware of Object.assign but I would need to have it also working on IE

Comment: As  mentioned in my question I need ES5 solutions Object.assign() is ES6  for my understanding.

Comment: Yep. got it.

I could simplify options to this  level


`var options = {
    duration: optionsArg.duration ||  _defaultOptions.duration,
    delay:  optionsArg.delay || _defaultOptions.delay,
    iterations: optionsArg.iterations ||  _defaultOptions.iterations,
    direction: optionsArg.direction || _defaultOptions.direction,
    fill: optionsArg.fill ||  _defaultOptions.fill,
  };`

Comment: Thanks for trying, but this does not work if developer does not pass any options at all, example https://jsfiddle.net/b379wyu9/ like using `animate(dom);`

Comment: This doesn't even resemble a code review. Please elaborate in your 'review'.